# Excel VBA Creating ActiveX Combobox Dynamically is Returning Non-ActiveX Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

Have declared a `Global` variable `As OLEObject` in `Modules.Module1` and am creating combobox dynamically, if not exist at `workbook_open()` by calling the following function

```
Public Function GetOrCreateComboBox(wsName As String, rngAddress As String, cmbName As String) As OLEObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cmb As OLEObject
    Dim cmbExists As Boolean
    
   ' On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        ' Worksheet does not exist, return Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Check if ActiveX combobox already exists on the worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set cmb = ws.OLEObjects(cmbName)
    
    
    cmbExists = Not cmb Is Nothing
    If Not cmbExists Then
        Dim existingCmb As OLEObject
        Dim cmbFound As Boolean
        cmbFound = False
        
        ' Check if any ActiveX combobox with name containing "Combobox" exists on the worksheet
        For Each existingCmb In ws.OLEObjects
            If InStr(1, existingCmb.Name, "Combobox", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' An existing combobox with "Combobox" in its name is found
                existingCmb.Delete  ' Delete the existing combobox
                Exit For
            End If
        Next existingCmb
        
        ' Create a new ActiveX combobox
        Set cmb = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                                   Left:=ws.Range(rngAddress).Left, _
                                   Top:=ws.Range(rngAddress).Top, _
                                   width:=ws.Range(rngAddress).width, _
                                   height:=ws.Range(rngAddress).height)
        
        ' Assign the specified name to the newly created combobox
        cmb.Name = cmbName
    Else
        ' If the ActiveX combobox already exists, just set the cmb variable to it
        Set cmb = ws.OLEObjects(cmbName)
        With cmb
            .Top = ws.Range(rngAddress).Top
            .Left = ws.Range(rngAddress).Left
            .width = ws.Range(rngAddress).width
            .height = ws.Range(rngAddress).height
         End With
         'MsgBox cmb.Name
    End If
    
    Set GetOrCreateComboBox = cmb ' Return the ComboBox reference
End Function
```

The code creates an ActiveX Combobox but returns Non-ActiveX combobox Handle. Please note that the `len(<variable_name>)` is `<= 32`.

After creating the combobox, when attempting to perform any action, including `.Clear` is causing runtime error 438 (Object does't support this property or method).

Can someone help me and explain why this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your above function returns an `OLEObject`, which may be a lot of objects/controls. Try using it as in the next example:

Call the function to return the object and use its `Object` property:

```
 dim mOLE as OlEObject, myCB as msforms.ComboBox
 set mOLE = GetOrCreateComboBox(wsName, rngAddress, cmbName)
 
 set myCB = mOLE.Object
 With myCB 'you will also benefit of intellisense suggestions
   .Clear
   '.......
 End With
```

Use this way in case you want using the function returning other `OLEObject` types, too. Adding a new parameter to specify it.

But wanting it to only return an `ActiveX` combo box, it would be enough to make the function returning what you need:

```
Public Function GetOrCreateComboBox(wsName As String, rngAddress As String, cmbName As String) As msforms.combobox
   'your existing code...
   '...
   'replace: Set GetOrCreateComboBox = cmb
   'with:
   Set GetOrCreateComboBox = cmb.Object
End Function
```

And it can be used as:

```
dim myCB as msforms.combobox
set myCB = GetOrCreateComboBox(wsName, rngAddress, cmbName)

Debug.print myCB.Name
```

Comment: No sir. Not working

Comment: @Raky It should work if you did what I suggested... What version did you choose? If the second one, of course, you should declare the variable receiving the function return `As msforms.combobox`... I edited my answer and show how to use the adapted function.

Comment: My Office Version is 2013. its a Excel VBA Code

Comment: At thist stage `Set GetOrCreateComboBox = cmb.Object' the `cmb.Object`is showing `Nothing`in the Tooltip

Comment: At thist stage `Set GetOrCreateComboBox = cmb.Object` the `cmb.Object` is showing as `Nothing` in the Tooltip. Also, the `OLEType=2`.

Comment: @Raky How did you see that? Does the code raise an error on that line? Anyhow, this has nothing to do with my answer. If so, this only means that your function does not return anything. Did you try first version? I mean, keep the function as it was, call and use as it is shown in this first version. If it does not work, do you have AnyDesk installed and if so, do you accept a remote connection? I cannot understand what's happening in your installation. This is basic VBA...

Comment: @FaneDaru I Can do Google Meet

Comment: @Raky What can I do with Google Meet? Can I make some tests on your computer, to see its responds to my debugging tests? If I only see, this is almost the same thing as happening here. I'm telling you something and you answer in your way... Can you install AnyDesk? If not, I am afraid I cannot help you, anymore. I do not understand what's happening in your computer.